# Accessing Checkbox Status Inside Listbox in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem in accessing the checkbox checked status that is residing inside a listview. If I have 4 or 5 rows, it is working fine. But where there are 50+ rows, it just stopped working. Following is the code.

```
ListView lst1= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst1);

CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbSpeciality);
for (int i=0;i< specialties.length;i++)
{
  cb = (CheckBox)lst1.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.cbSpeciality);
  if(cb.isChecked()){

   Log.d("asdf", "Gijo" );
   itemSelectedNameJson.put(specialties[i].getName());
   itemSelectedIdJson.put(specialties[i].getId());

    }
 }
```

Comment: any error coming? if yes crash report required

Comment: What do you mean by "it just stop working" ? Your app crash ? The value return is wrong ?

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.androhub.com/android-listview-checkbox/).

Comment: I get the error in this line of code inside the loop.                                        cb = (CheckBox)lst1.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.cbSpeciality); I think it's a memory issue after iteration a number of times. Is there any way to redeclare the check box each time it is accessed and checked for the status?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a list of 10 items in the listview. If you click on item number 9, you check the checkbox assigned to it, is that correct?

The object itself should have a corresponding variable that changes when it's checked/unchecked. When you create your listview you should check that variable and check/uncheck accordingly.

Comment: Instead of adding each check box click from the adapter, which I tried  before, but prefer this way of getting the check box status from the activity page, so as to avoid adding removing data from the array on each click.